# How to create string representation of Pandas DataFrame rows with currency fields?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame with many fields and two float fields for currency (Brazillian Reais). I need to be able to get a string representation, as a list of strings (each row is a string where every column has a separator. eg. `;`).

I've found a way to do it with:

```
import pandas as pd

def get_trades(df):
    list_of_list = df.astype(str).values.tolist()
    return ["; ".join(x) for x in list_of_list]
```

Example input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Date": ["10/10/2019", "12/11/2019"],
        "Operation": [" B ", " S "],
        "Quantity": [10, 100],
        "Unit cost (R$)": [10.20, 30.50],
        "Total cost (R$)": [102.0, 3050],
    }
)
```

Expected output:

```
["10/10/2019;  B ; 10; R$ 10,20; R$ 102,00",
 "12/11/2019;  S ; 100; R$ 30,50; R$ 3050,00"]
```

Actual output:

```
["10/10/2019;  B ; 10; 10.2; 102.0",
 "12/11/2019;  S ; 100; 30.5; 3050.0"]
```

The problem is that the float numbers are not showing as currency. I also tried using locale and currency configurations but it had no effect whatsoever:

```
def get_trades(df):
    loc = "pt_BR.utf8"
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, loc)
    pd.set_option("float_format", locale.currency)
    list_of_list = df.astype(str).values.tolist()
    return ["; ".join(x) for x in list_of_list]
```

Any idea of how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried creating string columns in the format you wish before running your function? Something like:

```
df['unit_cost_rs'] = df['Unit cost (R$)'].apply(lambda x: "R$" + str("{:.2f}".format(x).replace(".", ",")))
df['total_cost_rs'] = df['Total cost (R$)'].apply(lambda x: "R$" + str("{:.2f}".format(x).replace(".", ",")))
df = df.drop(columns=['Unit cost (R$)','Total cost (R$)'])
print(df)
```

Would give this resultant df:

```
         Date Operation  Quantity unit_cost_rs total_cost_rs
0  10/10/2019        B         10      R$10.20      R$102,00
1  12/11/2019        S        100      R$30.50     R$3050,00
```

And then you can run your function on this new df

Comment: thanks for the answer, it almost solves it. But with that the numbers are separated by dot instead of comma, that is way I tried locale. It formats as comma by default for pt_BR.

Comment: what about replacing the dot on the string. I know it's an ugly solution, but i think it works. I'll edit it so you can see

Comment: That does the work, thanks! And welcome to Stackoverflow! You got your first answer =)